# Response.TransmitFile(filePath) fails in child page in IE

Tags: c#

I try to load a small pdf file to client browser. I redirect to download_page.aspx that does the following:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();  
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
Response.Clear();  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");  
Response.TransmitFile(file);  
Response.Flush();
```

**Problem:**
When I redirect to download_page.aspx from a link or from a `button.OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('download_page.aspx?index=20')"` 
it works. PDF opens in client browser.
However, when I click on a button that does something on the page and then i use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to redirect to download_page.aspx`, then download_page.aspx just blinks (flashes) and closes, no pdf loaded.
This is IE7, IE8 problem. It works in Firefox.
Any help appreciated.
Thank you,
Raman.

Comment: I maybe not following, but it seem the inline content disposition would be what you want, no?

Comment: Yes. That was it. I changed content to inline and file loaded fine. Thank you liho1yey.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to ClearHeaders Clear and Flush, so your code should look like:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");  
Response.TransmitFile(file);
```

Now, you should also improve the **Content-Disposition** header value and add the file name to ease end-users browser experience. IE is different than other with regards with how the file name can be encoded in case it has special characters, so here is a sample code that you might use or change to your will:

```
public static void AddContentDispositionHeader(HttpResponse response, string disposition, string fileName)
{
    if (response == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("response");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(disposition + "; filename=\"");
    string text;
    if ((HttpContext.Current != null) && (string.Compare(HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser, "IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
    {
        text = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        text = fileName;
    }
    sb.Append(text);
    sb.Append("\"");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", sb.ToString());
}
```

Now, your code can be written as:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
AddContentDispositionHeader(Response, "attachment", filename);  
Response.TransmitFile(file);
```

The last thing is: make sure nobody deletes the files or writes to it during its transmission.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same condition as yours.

I finally solved it.

Don't use `window.open`. You can simply use

```
 window.location = 'download_page.aspx?index=20'
```

Note that the original page will remain well.

Reference from [here](http://blog.roodo.com/lovemai073/archives/11953517.html#comment-21770065) and from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-TW/236/thread/2265e633-37ec-49ff-807c-81e13bacd54a)